# Correct logic but incorrect code for calculating dates

Tags: c#, datetime, timespan

I'm writing a program to calculate timespans and cant seem to get the math correct.

What I'm basically trying to do is calculate if a particular date range is between an arrival date and an end date.

(----(--------------)------)
This one represents the arrival date and end date with the entered date range as the inner brackets. I basically don't care about the dates that are outside of the inner brackets, just checking to see if they're within the outer range, if that makes sense.

But another problem presents itself in that if we have an arrival and end dates that overlap the entered date range what do we do there?

We only care about the dates overlapping the dates entered. All of this makes sense to me I'm just not sure how to present it in code, the below example tries to accomplish the latter (albeit rather sloppily) would there be a more efficient way of doing this that would actually yield the correct result?

```
        DateTime arrivalDate = new DateTime(2012,10,15);
        DateTime releaseDate = new DateTime(2013,01,20);
        DateTime enteredDate = new DateTime(2012,10,01);
        DateTime enteredEnd = new DateTime(2012,12,31);

        TimeSpan begin = TimeSpan.MinValue;
        TimeSpan end = TimeSpan.MinValue;

        if (arrivalDate <= enteredDate)
            begin = enteredDate - arrivalDate;

        else if (arrivalDate >= enteredDate)
            begin = arrivalDate - enteredDate;

        if (releaseDate <= enteredEnd)
            end = enteredEnd - releaseDate;

        else if (releaseDate >= enteredEnd)
            end = releaseDate - enteredEnd;

        TimeSpan total = begin + end;
        TimeSpan benchmark = releaseDate - arrivalDate;
        TimeSpan other = benchmark - total;

        Console.WriteLine("There are " + begin.Days + " days in begin.");
        Console.WriteLine("There are " + end.Days + " days in end.");

        Console.WriteLine("There are " + other.Days + " days in the range.");
```

Comment: What is the purpose of all these calculations?  It doesn't seem that your question text explains what they are for and it certainly does not explain how they are different from your expected result.  If all you want to do is determine whether the range [enteredDate to enteredEnd] is within the range [arrivalDate to releaseDate], all you need is `bool isWithinRange = (arrivalDate <= enteredDate) && (enteredEnd <= releaseDate);`

Comment: That would work for the first part of it, but what if i wanted to determine the overlap? Say for example the arrival date is 12-10-15 and the releaseDate is 12-10-31 (october 31st), yet the entered date is 12-10-01 and the entered end is 12-10-31 meaning I would only care about 16 of the dates entered or if the arrival date was before  the entered date but the release date was say october 20th, so I would only care about the dates within that range.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To determine the amount of overlap:

```
DateTime arrivalDate = new DateTime(2012, 10, 15);
DateTime releaseDate = new DateTime(2013, 01, 20);
DateTime enteredDate = new DateTime(2012, 10, 01);
DateTime enteredEnd = new DateTime(2012, 12, 31);

// Whichever of { arrivalDate, enteredDate } is later
DateTime startOverlap = arrivalDate <= enteredDate ? enteredDate : arrivalDate;
// Whichever of { releaseDate, enteredEnd } is earlier
DateTime endOverlap = enteredEnd <= releaseDate ? enteredEnd : releaseDate;

TimeSpan totalOverlap = endOverlap - startOverlap;

Console.WriteLine("There are {0} days of overlap.", totalOverlap.Days);
```

To then determine whether the entered range is within the expected range:

```
TimeSpan enteredRange = enteredEnd - enteredDate;

bool isWithinRange = enteredRange == totalOverlap;
```